# Javascript undefined value instead of value

Tags: javascript, undefined

So I have these two for loops. In the first loop the message says exactly what I want it to say; `Hello Herbert, Hello Peter`.

But in the second one it says; `Hello undefined`.

What is the difference between these two blocks of code, and why does the second one returns `undefined`?

```js
let people = [
    {
        name: "Herbert",
        occupation: "Vildstaed",
        language: ["Finnish", "English", "German"]
    },
    {
        name: "Peter",
        occupation: "Skalnstead",
        language: ["German", "Livonian Dialect"]
    }
];

for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
    alert("Hello " + people[i].name)
}

for(let person in people) {
    alert("Hello " + person.name)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`For in` loop will return to you the `keys`, not the objects. So for the second case you the `person` is not the one which you expect. You can see it by showing only the `person`.

```js
let people = [
    {
        name: "Herbert",
        occupation: "Vildstaed",
        language: ["Finnish", "English", "German"]
    },
    {
        name: "Peter",
        occupation: "Skalnstead",
        language: ["German", "Livonian Dialect"]
    }
];

for(let person in people) {
    alert("Hello " + person)
}
```

To do what you want you can use `for of` loop instead in `ES6` version or just get by key

```js
let people = [
    {
        name: "Herbert",
        occupation: "Vildstaed",
        language: ["Finnish", "English", "German"]
    },
    {
        name: "Peter",
        occupation: "Skalnstead",
        language: ["German", "Livonian Dialect"]
    }
];

for(let person of people) {
    alert("Hello " + person.name)
}

for(let person in people) {
    alert("Hello " + people[person].name)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let people = [
    {
        name: "Herbert",
        occupation: "Vildstaed",
        language: ["Finnish", "English", "German"]
    },
    {
        name: "Peter",
        occupation: "Skalnstead",
        language: ["German", "Livonian Dialect"]
    }
];

for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
    alert("Hello " + people[i].name)
}

for(let person in people) {
    console.log(person);
    alert("Hello " + people[person].name)
}
```

As you can see the values person is getting is the index of the array, hence you need to access it using people[person]

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let person of people) {
   alert("Hello " + person.name)
}
```